# run program in background without while loop or windows scheduler

Tags: c#

I currently have a program which runs on a schedule and runs every half an hour. But i would like to program running continuously in the background. I now it can be done using a while loop and a thread making it sleep for the time i would like, it also can be done using the windows task scheduler. As i am extracting data from various api's and as they have a hierarchy they can throw an exception at any point, so currently my system throws the exception and carries onto the next method so on some data fails to extract not all, but if we are to use while it will leave it. All the times that the data has to be extracted the detials of the API is on a database, so i would like it to keep checking the database to see if any clients data has to be extracted. if a clients data has to be extracted at that time then it starts the extraction. my current system already work like the windows scheduler.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can use a timer. But a timer is like a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay to get a constant time and make a schedule inside of that function which would have the program run everytime the timeofday function reaches that time. You would still have to use an if statement though:

if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == your set time)
   run program;

Comment: How would this be any different than using windows task scheduler?

Comment: From reading his question I understood that he couldn't use a while loop or windows task scheduler, so this would be the samething without using those two tasks.

Comment: Right, but it seems that he already has something like this in place `my current system already work like the windows scheduler` Also, he wants it to run every half an hour, how would this achieve that? Frankly though, I think it's a poor question with not enough info to answer thoroughly.

Comment: I agree with you there. It's hard to understand exactly what is being asked. My final thought is that he would have to put it on a 30 minute timer or try using what I was saying earlier and use an if statement set to every half an hour lol

Comment: Yep totally, have a +1 for the effort though. I think running it via task scheduler would be fine and the real issue is probably around his exception handling

Answer (score 1):

You can create windows service for your task and you can also handle the exception related to your database.